# Can I use some file-tree selector which exists on graphical IDEs?

Tags: filesystem

It is normally on the left side, and it enables a fast switching between files in a complex directory hierarchy.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Vim comes with a built-in file explorer called netrw. If you have a reasonaby recent Vim, the following command will give you the kind of feature you are missing:

```
:Lexplore
```

See `:help netrw`.

Answer (score 4):

If **nerdtree** set:

```
let g:NERDTreeWinPos = "right"
```

Answer (score 4):

[NerdTree](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree) is commonly used for this, but you may want to take a look at [Oil and vinegar - split windows and the project drawer](http://vimcasts.org/blog/2013/01/oil-and-vinegar-split-windows-and-project-drawer/) , which makes an argument against using it.

If you choose to go this way, [tpope/vim-vinegar](https://github.com/tpope/vim-vinegar) is an extension that enhances the build in directory browser.

Comment: +1 for the article. It can really change your view on the way of using windows in vim. [Here](https://github.com/jeetsukumaran/vim-filebeagle) is another filesystem navigation plugin inspired by it.

Answer (score 2):

When I was transitioning to vim away from other editors, I wanted both a project drawer on the left and good tab functionality.

I started to use [NERDTreeTabs](https://github.com/jistr/vim-nerdtree-tabs), which is NERDTree, except optimized for use with multiple tabs. In particular, there is only one NERDTree now, and if you change tabs, the NERDTree is still there. So it really feels like a project drawer like you might find in other editors. Here's an example use.

[image]

You can customize the width of the NERDTree if you want. You might also set it to automatically close after use.

This works reasonably well with splits, but as in [Chad's answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/62/130), there are difficulties with NERDTree and splits.